# Bash console in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to connect the browser with the bash console using NodeJS.

Is there any node modules that do this? I don't want *to reinvent the wheel*, but if there aren't I will build one. I am sure that the web-sockets will be needed.

For example I like so much [Cloud9](http://c9.io) console.

Also, see the screen shot:

> [image: Cloud9 console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. [**tty.js**](https://github.com/chjj/tty.js) does the job.

It's well documented, and it also contains an example.

> [image: tty console]